# Subscribe to different event bus in same class

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I am using the `GreenRobot Event Bus 3.0` as an event bus and I have 2 publishers:

```
 private static final EventBus EVENT_BUS = new EventBus();

//Publish event to the event bus
public static void sendEvent(LoggingEvent event){
    LogPublisher.EVENT_BUS.post(event);
}

//Publish event to the event bus
public static void sendEvent(OtherLoggingEvent event){
    LogPublisher.EVENT_BUS.post(event);
}
```

I have 2 subscribers:

```
 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.ASYNC)
    public void onEvent(LoggingEvent event){
        logEvent( event);
    }

 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.ASYNC)
    public void onEvent(OtherLoggingEvent event){
        logEvent( event);
    }
```

The issue is when make a call like:

`MyPublisher.sendEvent(new OtherLoggingEvent(varA, varB, varC));`

Both subscribers are called and I can't figure out why. I think it might have something to do with the fact that `OtherLoggingEvent` is a subclass of `LoggingEvent`, but I'm not sure. My question then becomes how do I maintain a 1-1 relationship with the publisher and subscriber. I want to call:

```
MyPublisher.sendEvent(new OtherLoggingEvent(varA, varB, varC));
```

and have the subscriber `public void onEvent(OtherLoggingEvent event)` called and when I call:

```
MyPublisher.sendEvent(new LoggingEvent(varD, varE, varF));
```

the subscriber:

```
 public void onEvent(LoggingEvent event)
```

will be called? Will this work as is, but have to make sure that the classes are unique, and not a subclass of each other? Do I have to create a new `EventBus` object?

Comment: I suggest you to create a new instance of EventBus while posting updates as : **EventBus.getDefault().post(something_here)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both subscribers calling because of the event class inheritance. But you can switch off this `eventInheritance` feature in EventBus itself. By using this method:

```
EventBus BUS = EventBus.builder().eventInheritance(false).installDefaultEventBus();
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! I thought it might have something to do with the fact that one of the subscribing classes inherited from the other. This worked like a charm, just the way I need it to.